# Indentation level of multi-line case class in scalastyle

Tags: scala, scalastyle

Scalastyle marks the indentation of the first argument of all case classes that are split on multiple lines as wrong.

```
case class Theme(
  id: String,  <-- "Use correct indentation"
  name: String,
  start: Long
)
```

This is my `scalastyle_config.xml`:

```
<scalastyle>
    <name>Scalastyle standard configuration</name>
    <check enabled="true" class="org.scalastyle.file.IndentationChecker" level="warning"/>
</scalastyle>
```

Is it possible to set it not to mark it as faulty?
I have fiddled around with these parameters without success:

```
 <parameter name="tabSize">2</parameter>
 <parameter name="methodParamIndentSize">2</parameter>
```

I use version 0.8.0 of the SBT plugin and run it with `sbt scalastyle`

Comment: What version of Scalastyle are you using? Are you using the sbt plugin, or the standalone jar?

Comment: 0.8.0 as SBT plugin.